# SDO Oracle Table not recognized as Geometry in QGIS

Tags: qgis, oracle-spatial

I can connect to the Oracle Database with **QGIS** but spatial table/layers are not recognized as such.

I have read the following in the QGIS documentation:

> Normally, an Oracle Spatial layer is defined by an entry in the
>   USER_SDO_METADATA table.
>   *Source:* [QGIS Oracle connection documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html#connecting-to-oracle-spatial)

But I have not found this in the database and I cannot edit it.

The layers were created with ArcMap (so with [ArcSDE](http://downloads.esri.com/support/documentation/sde_/706understanding_arcsde.pdf)). I know under ArcMap the spatial layers are recognized.
I found that the following tables has informations about spatial tables:

[image]
[image]

Is it an option to overwrite USER_SDO_METADATA table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [commented by @Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/319243/sdo-oracle-table-not-recognized-as-geometry-in-qgis#comment520578_319243):

> To the best of my knowledge, QGIS doesn't read SDE.ST_GEOMETRY, which
>   won't have an entry in `USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA`. You'd need to change
>   your enterprise geodatabase configuration to use SDO_GEOMETRY then
>   recreate the table before QGIS can see the table. It would be unwise
>   to let QGIS modify rows in a versioned feature class.